# Sinking cue ball after the 8 ball in pool

Tags: rules, pool

When I designate the pocket I'm putting the 8-ball and I am successful and then follow it in with the cue ball - do I still win?

Answer (score 8):

According to Wikipedia, a player will win if

> The opposing player commits any foul, including scratching the cue ball into a pocket, or knocking it off the table, in the course of a shot that pockets the 8 ball

Therefore, you would lose because you scratch the cue ball into the pocket while pocketing the 8 ball.

[Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-ball#Winning)

Answer (score 1):

In one shot pool, played with 2 1/4 inch balls on American type square pocketed pool table,  the rule is: re-spot the black and incoming player has ball in hand that to say "put anywhere on the table" with one shot only.

When playing European/UK/Australia/South Africa "2 shot pool" on basically a mini snooker table with a rounded shape to the pockets, often times played with reds and yellow balls,  the rule is: loss of game on any foul whilst potting the black ball.

Answer (score 0):

[IBA rules](https://www.ibapool.com/Membership/EightBall) : loss of game

> A shooter loses the game if he commits any of the following infractions:
>
> ...
>
> 5. Cue ball scratches or is a “jumped ball” while shooting the 8-ball.

[UPA Tour rules](https://upatour.com/8-ball-rules/) : loss of game

> 7.2 Scratch
>
> Pocketing the cue ball or driving it off the table is a ball in hand foul. Scratching on the 8-ball is not a loss of game as long as the 8-ball was not pocketed.

[APA rules](https://media.poolplayers.com/TMRB/Rules-Booklet-English.pdf) : loss of game

> 16. HOW TO WIN A GAME
>
> 8-Ball
>
> ...
>
> e. Your opponent fouls the cue ball and pockets
> the 8-ball.